# Logout Action with Asp.Net Core Cookie Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have implemented authentication in Asp.Net Core 2.2 like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync(string user, string password)
    {
        if (user == "admin" && password == "admin")
        {
            var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin") };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        {
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Users");
        }
```

I need to make a Logout action now. I used to achieve this in Asp.Net MVC with FormsAuthentication.SignOut()... I need to know the proper way to do it in Asp.Net Core 2.2

What I've tried is to make a Logout action like this:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
```

And used the following code in my NavBar:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.Name + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Users/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
                                <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
                </ul>
            }
```

Following instructions from this [documentaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#log-out)

This correctly shows the Logout button, but pressing the button doesn't seem to trigger my action, and the user is not logged out.

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you try so far? What does the docs says about this?

Comment: @vasily.sib I tried making a Logout action with HttpContext.SignOutAsync(), and then proceeded to make a form with an asp-page="Users/Logout" tag and a submit button inside, but after clicking the button, nothing happens... My button doesn't seems to trigger my action.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to show that. Show us your `Logout` action (with all attributes that you apply to it) and a form that you use to trigger that action

Comment: Have you try to debug it? Do you actually hit your `Logout` action? If you open developer console in your browser what response from server do you receive on that button click?

Comment: I wasn't hitting my action after all... Silly mistakes were made. Thanks for your help Vasily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out I was simply making a mistake in my View. I was calling the wrong action in my form.

> using (Html.BeginForm("<s>LogOff</s>", "<s>Account</s>", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))

Should've been,`Html.BeginForm("Logout","Users", ...)`

Also, my form was sending a Post request, so my action had to be decorated with `[HttpPost]`, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but HttpPost didn't work for me. I changed it to HttpGet and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you want to use an a tag:

```
<form asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="parentNode.submit();">
        <span>Logout</span>
    </a>
</form>
```